# WebStorm automatically go to the next line while coding

Tags: webstorm

I want WebStorm automatically go to a new line when I paste / write something that's longer than X characters, but I couldn't make it work.

`Editor > Code Style > Default Options > Right Margin >` Set to 120 and enabled "wrap on typing"

`Editor > General > Soft Wraps > Use soft wraps in editor` is enabled

`View > Active Editor > Use Soft Wraps` is enabled.

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this box: `Editor > Code Style > [x] Wrap when typing reaches right margin`. However, this doesn't work for pasting text, but you may type something (like a space) after pasting to force the wrap.

You may also look into your code style settings. In your example (JS), go to `Editor > Code Style > JavaScript > Wrapping and Braces` and adjust your settings.